# RewriteRule issue - robots.txt

Tags: mod-rewrite

my current .htaccess has

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.txt$ /404.php [r=301,nc]
```

Its happened that, all `.txt` files get redirect to `404.php`.

Code looks like ok for me, but this will redirect request for robots.txt file also.
I want to unblock only `robots.txt` file and keep other `.txt` file links redirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the **robots.txt** file from the rule using one of the following options :

1. regex negitive lookahed :

   RewriteRule ((?!robots).+).txt$ /404.php [r=301,nc]
2. negitive rewriteCond

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt$
   RewriteRule ^(.+).txt$ /404.php [r=301,nc]
3. skip the /robots.txt

   RewriteRule robots.txt$ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^(.+).txt$ /404.php [r=301,nc]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below set of rules

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.txt$ /404.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the htaccess file ? Anyway I have changed the flags. Please try again with this ones more. I tested it in localhost and its working fine.